# Skyrim adlevel cheat not working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing skyrim and I was trying to level up my character by typing in the cheat, player.adlevel. Every time I did, it would just say, could not parse this line. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no player.addlevel in Skyrim which is why you are receiving the error.

Player.SetLevel [#]

Sets the player level. However, it does not grant the experience you would gain normally, it just modifies the level.

Alternatives are:

Player.AddPerk [perk ID]
Adds the specified perk.

AdvSkill [[[[[Skill|skill]]|skill]]] [#]

Source: https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/PC_Console_Command_Cheats

Comment: Just note that AddPerk is notorious for being super buggy.  Don't use it unless you plan to restart your save.